# Specs2: Generate HTML report?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, sbt, specs2, html-rendering

I am using specs2 to generate html test reports. But, I am getting one `com.company.package.SomeSpec.html` per spec. Is it possible to generate a single page html report for ALL my tests or atleast generate an index.html also which links to other tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the User Guide, ["How to create an index"](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.HowTo.html#Create+an+index)

```
import org.specs2._
import runner.SpecificationsFinder._

class index extends Specification { def is =

  examplesLinks("Example specifications")

  // see the SpecificationsFinder trait for the parameters of the 'specifications' method
  def examplesLinks(t: String) = t.title ^ specifications().map(see)
}
```